# Install High Sierra on a dual booted MBP [Mac 10.11.6 and Windows 7]

Tags: dual-boot

I have a Late 2011 13" MBP running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

I needed to run some windows apps on my lappy so I used Boot Camp Assistant to partition --the only storage disk my laptop-- a 250 GB SSD and install Windows 7 on it.

Now I need some Mac apps that require a newer version of OS X to run, What's the best way to install High Sierra and have all the three OS's?

I'm a Mac noobie so please go easy on me :)

Comment: Boot camp is great for what it does and no more: Dual boot macOS and Windows. Installing a 3rd OS is going to cause major problems with Boot Camp partition to the point where it won't boot. Your best bet is making a backup of your boot camp (try saying that 10 times fast), removing it. Creating 3 partions (one for each os), installing High Sierra on one, and then finding a way to install windows without bootcamp.

Comment: Take a look at https://lifehacker.com/5531037/how-to-triple-boot-your-mac-with-windows-and-linux-no-boot-camp-required

Comment: @JBis Thanks a lot for the answer, so if I got it right I should backup and remove Boot Camp partition, install High Sierra, install rEFIt and then install Winodws 7 with it :)

Comment: Yeah I guess that would work. I can try to help if you run into issues. Also, please write a detailed solution after you have successfully done what you're trying to do so other users can do it too :). **But please make sure you backup everything** macOS partition and windows partition.